# Running HttpRequest synchronously C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have two functions- let's call them A and B.

- B is a function that sends an HTTP Request to a server, and returns a Dictionary back.
- A is a function that calls B, then uses it's returned Dictionary in a couple of different code lines.

I'm trying to make function A wait for function's B result.
As well as the parsing at the end of function A to wait for the HTTP Response.

I couldn't figure out how can I get it done since `HttpClient` requires `Async` work, while I need to avoid it from running on a different thread,
since I need the whole code to wait for the response.

I've tried using a Task return value, converting function B to a class, using await in the response variable and what not. couldn't get it done =(

```
protected async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> B()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products"))
        {
            var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CC"));
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents);
            Dictionary<string, string> existing = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var attr in attributes)
            {
                existing.Add(attr.name, "" + attr.id);
            }
            return existing;
        }
    }
}
```

and Function A:

```
void A(){
    Dictionary<string, string> existingAttr = B();
    // Then Does some code with existingAttr
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Add(string, string)' ilegal arguments"

Probably because the response wasn't full by that point.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make `A` async and `await` the call to `B`?

Comment: Just another [misuse of HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Dictionary<string, string> existingAttr = B();
```

Doesn't work because `B()` is returning a `Task<Dictionary<string, string>>`, not just a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Since this is ASP.NET, there is no reason to make it synchronous. Plus, it would just make trouble. It will. Don't do it.

Make everything `async`.

```
async Task A(){
     Dictionary<string, string> existingAttr = await B();
     // Then Does some code with existingAttr
}
```

Make whatever calls `A()` `async` too and use `await A()`, all the way up to the Controller.

*Update:* Your "illegal arguments" error didn't make sense to me at first, since that kind of error would normally be thrown at compile time. But I looked a little closer and noticed this:

```
dynamic attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents);
```

Because `attributes` is `dynamic`, the compiler doesn't know what actual type it will be until that code is actually run. So your exception happens here:

```
existing.Add(attr.name, "" + attr.id);
```

because you're feeding it something that is not a `string`. The expression `"" + attr.id` will likely come out as a string because of the concatenation. But `attr.name` won't be. When you use `JsonConver.DeserializeObject` to get a `dynamic` object, the actual type of the properties is [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm), not `string`.

You *can* use `.ToString()`:

```
existing.Add(attr.name.ToString(), attr.id.ToString());
```

But this is a good example of why you would be better off to create an actual class for your data:

```
public class MyAttributes {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

and deserialize into that type:

```
var attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyAttributes>>(contents);
```

That way, these kinds of errors get caught at compile time and you don't get nasty surprises later.

Comment: I made them both async but
When doing so, I get an error on ```existingAttr = await B().Result;```,
```"Dictionary<string, string>" does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string,string>' could be found```

Comment: Remove `.Result`.

Comment: Then I get 
```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message= 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.Add(string, string)' Includes ilegal arguments
```

Comment: Seems like it's coming from function B though, the first line of the stacktrace is:
```StackTrace:
   at wooAppForm.WebForm1.<GetExistingAttributes>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\CodingCode\source\repos\appForm\appForm\WebForm1.aspx.cs:line 434```

 which is the line of:
```existing.Add(attr.name, "" + attr.id);``` when it crashes and I hover on the word "attributes" (from the foreach loop in which line 434 exists- you can see it at the end of the first post), it seems like the array isn't full- the response is partly deserialized

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem. I've updated my answer to describe what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the await keyword. Await will insert a suspension point in the execution of the method B until the awaited task completes.